# Bash exiftool command

Tags: bash, if-statement, exiftool

I am trying to run an if statement on a exiftool variable set in a bash script.
Looking to trigger an action if the ProductVersion returns a particular version.
I get the below error when running the bash script
`sh testing.sh`

`testing.sh: 4: [: exiftool: unexpected operator`

Below is the script I am attempting to run:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
ExifCommand="exiftool -ProductVersion /serverdata/serverfiles/test/Server.exe"

if [ $ExifCommand =~ *3.7* ]; then
echo "testing success"
fi
```

Another thing to note, if I put the command in `ExifCommand=$(exiftool -ProductVersion /serverdata/serverfiles/test/Server.exe)` I get the below error:

`testing.sh: 3: Product: not found`

Comment: Check your script with shellcheck. Follow shellcheck recommendations.

Comment: You can't use `[` for regex matching. You would need `[[`. Also your regex is weird: An asterisk at the start is taken literally, so you are searching in your string for a literal asterisk, followed by a digit 3, followed by at least one more (arbitrary) character.

Comment: You are storing the text of a command in `ExifCommand`, but you seem to be assuming that you store the output obtained by running the command.

Comment: On the other hand, the message "`testing.sh: 3: Product: not found`" looks like it is being emitted by `exiftool`.  Why that's happening is an entirely separate question, probably unrelated to your script.  You should at minimum trying running your `exiftool` command directly from a shell prompt to check whether it fails in the same way.

Comment: @JohnBollinger That is correct, I am more used to scripting in powershell and what not, so differences in Bash, are beyond my tiny brain.

Comment: @JohnBollinger To answer the question, the command itself works if I run it outside of a variable, how do I go about putting the output of that command into its own variable, that is all I really need.

Comment: ^ Well, that and the if statement to recognise that if anywhere in the output 3.7 exists, that the if statement would return true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From comments:

> how do I go about putting the output of that command into its own variable

The way to capture the standard output of a command is to use a *command substitution*, which you already demonstrate in the question:
`$(some command)`.  That can be protected against word splitting by double-quoting it, and the result assigned to a variable if that's what you want.  For example:

```
ExifOutput="$(exiftool -ProductVersion /serverdata/serverfiles/test/Server.exe)"
```

You show a similar attempt in the question, which could well have been foiled by the absence of quotation marks.

The old-school / POSIX way of testing for a substring in that would be via a `case` statement:

```
case ${ExifOutput} in
  *3.7*) echo "testing success" ;;
esac
```

Note that there, the `*3.7*` is a glob pattern, not a regular expression.

There is a bash-specific alternative involving its internal conditional-evaluation command, `[[`, and a regular-expression matching operator `=~`.  That could be spelled like so:

```
if [[ "$ExifOutput" =~ .*3[.]7.* ]]; then
  echo "testing success"
fi
```

Note well that pathname expansion is not performed on the arguments of `[[`, else the regular expression would need to be quoted.  Note also that it is a *bona fide* regular expression (POSIX flavor), not a glob pattern.

Comment: Whenever I put the double square brackets in I get the below error:
testing.sh: 3: [[: not found

Comment: Then on top of that, if I set the variable like above, in double quotes, the command does not run as expected, I even removed exiftools command as a factor, and used something like ls -l, and that errors, unless I echo out the variable. Example: If I just run `$ExifOutput` it errors, but if I run `echo $exifOutput` I get the results I expect. Why is that?

Comment: My god I am stupid... as I said, I am fairly new(ish) to bash scripts, I have been running the script with sh myscript.sh instead of bash myscript.sh using the right execution method, and what do you know, it works haha

Comment: I see, @Crazyaussie21. That explains the issue with `[[`.  Note that instead of running `bash` explicitly, you have the option of making the script directly executable (`chmod u+x myscript.sh`, for example), then exucuting it directly (`./myscript.sh`).  Then the shebang line you already placed at the top will be used to determine with which shell to execute it.